# Controlling the OneSignal push notification time of display on screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, onesignal

I have implemented Push notifications with OneSignal (image below). I want to know if there is a way to control the time for which the notification should last on the user's screen? Is it possible using GCM/Firebase? Can I increase/decrease the time for the notification to last on the user's screen selectively, or is that not the purpose of push notifications?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. You can disable the *require interaction* function. Require function allows the notification to stay on the users device unless the user either clicks or clear it.
2. Enabling the Auto Hide feature. This ensures that they notification will automatically disappear in 20 secs of delivery.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am facing same issue but i am not using onesignal. how can disable default auto hide of web push notification?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vivek.will try if it works, glad you understood the problem without asking for more details :)